# How to fix problem of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException]

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So I just started learning Java, and I am facing this problem. My main is trying to call the method `getOperator` but it's giving me the `[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException]` error. How do I fix this?

```
    //get operator +, - or *
    public static char getOperator() 
    {
        //set operator as random to return different types
        //of operators from cases 0 to 2

        int oper =  rand.nextInt(3);// **error occurs on this line**


        switch (oper)
        {
            case 0: return '+'; //return as + if case is 0
            case 1: return '-'; //return as - if case is 1
            case 2: return '*'; //return as * if case is 2
            default: return '+'; //default will return as +
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assign a non-null value to `rand`?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the stack trace? It probably shows you exactly what is wrong in your code.

Comment: Random rand = new Random(); when you declare rand, you need to make it point at an actual object.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int oper =  rand.nextInt(3);// **error occurs on this line**
```

This will almost certainly mean `rand` is `null`. You need to assign a non-null value to `rand`. Perhaps something like:

```
private static final Random rand = new SecureRandom();
```